# Replace few dependency versions inside Spring-boot starter parent

Tags: maven, spring-boot, dependencies, pom.xml

How can I change few of dependencies of Spring-boot starter parent by pom.xml?
(requirement is to change couple of dependency versions while using starter parent)

Comment: which dependencies ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what may be the dependencies. The problem was caused by changing the parent version. As i identified,  Jackson is one such issue maker when version changes.

Comment: First question: Why would you like to change those versions?